# Java: Which mode is by default set in Javax Cipher class?

Tags: java, encryption, aes, ecb, block-cipher

I am working on securing a chat application written in Java (it is downloaded from the internet, and now I want to secure it in order to learn). I have read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html), but I am unable to figure out which mode of encryption is set by default, if I don't explicitly put one. Is it ECB? If so, what's the key differences between it and other modes of encryption in regards of a chat application? It's worth mentioning that I watched this [explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v1JwSaAqVNY) before posting here as I still couldn't figure out the answers to my questions.

The way I have encrypted/decrypted the messages transmitted is by:

- A client writes a message, which gets encrypted (AES) and sent to the server
- The server decrypts the message and broadcasts it to all the users on the server

I would say this is ECB.

I hope somebody can clarify it for me!

Comment: The default is provider-specific. There is no reason to use the default, and relying on it is a common source of portability bugs. Always fully specify the "algorithm/mode/padding" argument to `Cipher.getInstance()`.

Comment: What is meant by provider-specific?

Comment: Bab: if more than one person has commented on a post, as is the case here, and you respond to one in particular, you should use the '@ user' feature to notify them. But anyway, provider-specific means specific to (i.e. can vary and is determined by) the provider, and the concept of providers is fundamental to Java crypto (JCA); since you asked about j7 (which is obsolete, BTW) see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#Design (but it's substantially the same in current versions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the document you linked to, there is an example: `Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")` it uses `CBC` mode. The same document lists `ECB` as a valid mode for `AES`.

You will have to spell out the mode yourself.